# Laravel best naming convention for controller method and route

Tags: laravel, naming-conventions

I'm creating an ajax request to get item details

Here's what my controller method looks like.

```
class SystemItemsController extends Controller
  {
      function getDetails(Request $request){
       $response =  SystemItems::where('item_name', 'like', '%' .$name . '%')->get();
       return response()->json($response,200);
  }

  }
```

and my

routing name

`Route::get("/system-items/item-details","SystemItemsController@getStockDetails");`

question : what would be the best naming convention for my route(**`item-details`**) and method(**`getStockDetails`**)?

follow up Q : can i do this using laravel resource?

Answer (score 7):

You can use kebab-case and plural in the URI pattern, but camelCase and singular for Controller name, as that is what Laravel will look for if trying to do route–model binding.

You can use it for resouce routes, but note, for this route

```
Route::resource('item-details', 'ItemDetailController');
```

the route parameter will result in snake_case and singular

```
/item-details/{item_detail}
```

For the controller methods the conventional names are `index`, `show`, `create`, `store`, `edit`, `update` and `delete`. And snakeCase for custom methods.

Also you can add a route group to prefix with some uri like `/system-items`

```
Route::group(['prefix'  =>  'system-items'], function () {
    Route::resource('item-details', 'ItemDetailController');
});
```

run `php artisan route:list` to see the result

```
+--------+-----------+-----------------------------------------------------+-------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+
| Domain | Method    | URI                                                 | Name                    | Action                                                                    | Middleware   |
+--------+-----------+-----------------------------------------------------+-------------------------
|        | GET|HEAD  | api/v1/system-items/item-details                    | item-details.index      | App\Http\Controllers\Api\v1\ItemDetailController@index                         | api          |
|        | POST      | api/v1/system-items/item-details                    | item-details.store      | App\Http\Controllers\Api\v1\ItemDetailController@store                         | api          |
|        | GET|HEAD  | api/v1/system-items/item-details/create             | item-details.create     | App\Http\Controllers\Api\v1\ItemDetailController@create                        | api          |
|        | GET|HEAD  | api/v1/system-items/item-details/{item_detail}      | item-details.show       | App\Http\Controllers\Api\v1\ItemDetailController@show                          | api          |
|        | PUT|PATCH | api/v1/system-items/item-details/{item_detail}      | item-details.update     | App\Http\Controllers\Api\v1\ItemDetailController@update                        | api          |
|        | DELETE    | api/v1/system-items/item-details/{item_detail}      | item-details.destroy    | App\Http\Controllers\Api\v1\ItemDetailController@destroy                       | api          |
|        | GET|HEAD  | api/v1/system-items/item-details/{item_detail}/edit | item-details.edit       | App\Http\Controllers\Api\v1\ItemDetailController@edit
```

Of course, all of these are conventions and you can customize everything by doing it by hand and using your own conventions.